# Check Bit String on Double Null

Tags: algorithm, binary, pseudocode, bitstring

I have the task of writing an algorithm that get's a bit string length (if that's the proper tranlation to it) and counts all the Bit strings that don't contain a double null.

For example: "10101" would count, while "10010" wouldn't count.

My problem here is, that I don't know the right datatype for bitstring, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to find the number of bit strings of a given length that don't contain "00"?

You can do this in O(log(the_length)) time.  Good algorithms for this don't actually use any bit strings at all, so a bit string data type is not required.

If you want to actually make bit strings and count them, though, then use whatever is easiest for you -- either integers or strings of 1s and 0s.  Your language probably makes it easier to manipulate strings and check them for double zeros.  No matter what data type you use, this will take O(2^the_length) time. It's fine since you're just learning, but it's slow no matter what, so don't worry too much about choosing the most efficient representation.